# Call to unefined function db2_connect using zend

Tags: zend-framework

Warning: db2_connect() [function.db2-connect]: Statement Execute Failed

on execution it showing warning.

it showing line 65 and it is    'i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON,

in zend studio when i look code it showing call to unidentified function on db2_connect.

what are these options?

i try to connectdirectly using db2_connect with just simple php it work.

why undefined function .anything wit path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off showing us some code but looking around for that error message I found [this link](http://www.devx.com/ibm/Article/29366) that seems to address exactly that. Otherwise as I said just post the code that produces this error and we`ll give you better help.